# mysql in docker container can't start

Tags: mysql, docker

This started today and I couldn't figure it out.

Mysql docker container logs reveal this but I have no idea where to fix it and why it started all of a sudden.

Any idea?

```
2021-05-04T16:32:44.941492Z 0 [ERROR] unknown option '--root@cc1dd09ee7b4:/etc/mysql'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i started a new docker/mysql container and copied data directory from the old one , which "solved" the problem.